# Make Div into new Line

Tags: html, css

I have three div's

```
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="gallery"></div> 
<br/>                   
<div id="autoshootmsg" style="display: none;">          
   <span id="timer"></span>
   <span> seconds remaining</span>
</div>
```

I want this to be like the image below:

[image]

How will I do that through css? Below is my css code:

```
div#gallery
{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

div#example,
div#gallery
{    
    border: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black; 
    margin-left: 10px; 
}
div#example,
div#gallery
{
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the width correctly, it will work:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#example, #gallery, #autoshootmsg {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}

#example, #gallery {
    width: 50%;
}

#autoshootmsg {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The border-box model allows you to have the borders and padding as a part of width and height. This means that border and padding do not take extra space.

EDIT: Here is a [preview](http://codepen.io/gasim/pen/LEQXQe). You have to get rid of the space between inline block attributes. That's why I used the HTML comments "hack" on that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the autoshootmsg div to `display:inline-block` as well and make it wider.

```
div#autoshootmsg
{
    width: 640px; // Twice the width
    height: 240px;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use of this code for your box.

```html
<div id="allwrapper">
  <div class="top">
    <section class="t-left"></section>
    <section class="t-right"></section>
  </div>
  <div class="down">
     <section class="d-box"></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As i understand your question, following code will help you

```
<div id="example" style="border:solid 1px;float:left;width:49.5%;" >1</div>
<div id="gallery" style="border:solid 1px;float:left;width:49.5%;">2</div>
<br/>              
<div id="autoshootmsg" style="border:solid 1px;width:99%;"><span id="timer"></span> <span> seconds remaining</span></div>
```

**Demo-**http://jsfiddle.net/jsq2dcLa/

> Thank you